# ColdFusion 11 How to execute a block of code one at a time

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I need to execute a block of code one at a time per request. Wrapping the block of code with the cflock tag is not possible because the code runs for a long period of time thus easily times out (it is a call to webservice requiring lots of back and forth).

I tried the following technique to bypass the use of the cflock tag:

For each request, I increment an Application Variable (which is initialized to 1) and assign it to a Local Variable which represents the ranking of the request.

After one request finishes executing the long running code, I increment another Application Variable (which is initialized to 1 as well).

So for the subsequent requests, I compare their rankings to the latter Application Variable. So while the two values are not equal, then I do a loop.

Below is the code:

```
 <cflock timeout="1" type="exclusive" throwontimeout="true">
    <cfif NOT structKeyExists(APPLICATION,'currentRequestOrder')>
        <cfset APPLICATION.currentRequestOrder = 1>
        <cfset APPLICATION.nbRequestsRunning = 1>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset APPLICATION.nbRequestsRunning = APPLICATION.nbRequestsRunning + 1>
    </cfif>
</cflock>

<cfset thisRequestOrder = APPLICATION.nbRequestsRunning>

<cfloop condition="thisRequestOrder NEQ APPLICATION.currentRequestOrder">

</cfloop>

<long running of code>

</long running of code>

<cflock timeout="1" type="exclusive" throwontimeout="true">
    <cfif APPLICATION.currentRequestOrder LT APPLICATION.nbRequestsRunning>
        <cfset APPLICATION.currentRequestOrder = APPLICATION.currentRequestOrder + 1>
    </cfif>
</cflock>
```

The behavior of this code is that requests coming after the first one don't get past the loop. In other words the condition of the cfloop always evaluates to true.

The ultimate solution I'm looking for is to have the long running code to be executed once at a time per request.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. What you are describing sounds like a queue of sorts? Maybe back up a step and explain a) what this long running process does (in general terms) and b) why it must be executed one request at a time.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use cflock. Doesn't cflock do exactly what you are asking for?  If your code is long-running, then you're  likely to have issues single threading it regardless of the method you use.

Comment: If the requirement is to run it only once per request, then take away everything you've done to ensure that.  Doing nothing will accomplish your goal.  Mucking about with application variables is preventing it.

Comment: @Leigh Yes we can consider the problem of queueing. The long running process in general:  1- collects xml data from a webservice that can't be done in one call because of restrictions by the webservice's owner so I need to make several calls to obtain the full data. 2- After the xml data are fully fetched, then I transform that xml into another one xml data using CF Function xmlTransform. The xml source data itself is very long. It must be executed one request at a time because the transformed xml for the same xml input is different for two or more requests run simultaneously.

Comment: @BradWood cflock can do what I want but for best practices' reason, it is not recommended to set a high value of the "timeout" attribute

Comment: @tantely I guess I don't understand your requirements then.  If you are adamant that only one instance of this process can run at a time, then you need to block other requests for the duration of the time it takes for the first process to complete.  Am I missing something?? There's much you haven't shared with us, but if you want subsequent requests to just skip over, then leave a short timeout and set throwontimeout to false. Then the threads won't stack up, but just continue on after a few seconds of waiting.

Comment: @BradWood yes I really need to have requests to run the code block at a time, that's the reason why I shared with you the attempt I did to block other request until the first one completes but unfortunately that didn't work. In fact in addition to the long running web service calls, when I transform the full xml from the WS, the CPU Usage is almost 100% when 2 requests or more simultaneously execute the code block and when that happens, there are discrepancies in the transformed xml

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to help with information such as "that didn't work".  Nobody knows what that means.  If your process is already running and a second request comes in, what would you like the second request to do? Wait? Error? You've already been given the solution to both of those options.  I don't understand what you're even asking for at this point.

Comment: I agree with Brad. The solution to your question (as far as I can tell) is to use `cflock` around the code in question. That is what it is designed for. You say you can't do that because _it is not best practice_ and _it is not recommended to set a high value of the "timeout" attribute_. Well it is not recommended to single thread your application either, but that is what you are asking for.  And, yes, if you are single threading the requests, and those requests take a long time then your server is essentially "down" during that time as it cannot handle any more requests (they get queued).

Comment: Also, this does not sound like a good way to implement a queue for a long running process IMO.  Even if a request did not timeout, most users are not going to wait 5 or 10 minutes for a web page. They'll just skip to another page, leaving the abandoned request still running on the server causing other problems. Ultimately the real question is *why* do you think the requests must be single threaded? Throttling by the remote webservice, performance issues, etecetera?

Comment: @BradWood I've already explained in my initial post what is not working with my attempt. I need the 2nd request to wait. And at the end of my initial post, I said what is my exact need. I've just shared my attempt to solve my problem to express that I've already worked hard on my end before asking help.

Comment: @Miguel-F Yes I know cflock should do the job but then what is your approach?

Comment: @Leigh The reason why the request must be single threaded is because of the throttling by the remote webservice. I've already followed their constraints (2 requests/second) by using the CF function  sleep(700) but I still see difference in results returned by the remote webservice. so I thought having my requests  to the remote ws going one by one should definitely fix the discrepancies

Comment: @Tantely - So what do you expect to happen if more than 2 requests/second arrive on your server? Wait (for how long)? Not sure what the "discrepancies" are, but you definitely need to figure out the cause first. Without knowing more, there is no reason you should not be able to make multiple (independent) calls to a remote web services, so it might be a code bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Tantely I am not even to a point of understanding your issue to suggest an approach. If the web service has a 2 request per second limitation then i would presume that they would return some error when the 3rd request is made. Perhaps instead of limiting on your side just look for that error return and then wait 1second and request again. Really I am just guessing at this however without knowing more about the web service.

Answer (score 0):

We had a process that would go through a queue. Due to a memory leak in ColdFusion we didn't want it to process the queue all at once. Our resolution was to chain requests by calling a new one at the end of a previous one.

```
<cfif url.step lt 5>
    <cfhttp url="#currentTemplate#?step=#url.step+1#" timeout="0" />
</cfif>
```

or you can name the steps. Either way this is a way to prevent long running requests by breaking them up into steps. You can save intermediate data in a database, application variable, etc.